# Font awesome icon

Tags: icons, font-awesome

How can I get color icon of font awesome ?

Like I am using `fa fa-facebook` class to get a facebook icon. But it is not colorful. I need a font awesome colorful(facebook color) icon of facebook.

Comment: You can just use CSS to change the `color` of the element

Comment: You should have googled before asking this question. You just need to add a custom class and then add color with css :)

Comment: Thanks @masud_moni for your reply. I googled it before asking. I would not like to add custom class. I am looking for font awesome way. Thanks

Comment: Why you do not want to add custom class? I do not find whether there is any font awesome way or not. If there was, you must have found it also. Custom class seems the most appropriate way to me. Good day...:)

Answer (score 2):

You can style it with css, and if you want multiple color you can use gradient

```
<h1><i class="fa fa-facebook-official"></i></h1>


h1 {
    color: blue;
}
h1 {
    color: red; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
    color: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, yellow); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    color: -o-linear-gradient(red, yellow); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    color: -moz-linear-gradient(red, yellow); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    color: linear-gradient(red, yellow); /* Standard syntax */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change color by using css properties.

```
#elementID {
   color: #fff;
   text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
   font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

Comment: Avoid using ID in CSS; use class instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color of the font using custom CSS, for you case

```
.fa-facebook-square:before {
    color: #488dd8;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use css to color the font, You can use style tag like this down example:-

< li class="fa fa-facebook" style="color: #0000ff" > </li>